# Documentum: Failed to create document

Tags: document-management, http-status-code-500, documentum

I tried to upload a new document to [Documentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentum) via the [CMIS AtomPub API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services), and received the error message below. How to solve this error?

```
[CMIS AtomPub binding]

STATUS CODE:
500

EXCEPTION:
runtime

ERROR:
Failed to create document
[E_CREATING_OBJECT_TREE_FAILED_WITH_TREE_DUMP] \"Create\" operation failed for object: [New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[E_CREATE_CONTENTFUL_ACTION_FAILED] Create contentful action with identity: \"[New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]\" failed. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[E_CREATE_CONTENTFUL_ACTION_FAILED] Create contentful action with identity: \"[New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]\" failed. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[E_PERFORM_EXECUTION_FAILED] Failed to execute DFC operation: Could not check in document 'dfs-2061696922256532526.tmp'. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[DM_SYSOBJECT_E_LINK_PERMIT2] Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.

STACK TRACE:
org.cmis.ws.CmisException: Failed to create document
[E_CREATING_OBJECT_TREE_FAILED_WITH_TREE_DUMP] \"Create\" operation failed for object: [New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[E_CREATE_CONTENTFUL_ACTION_FAILED] Create contentful action with identity: \"[New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]\" failed. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[E_CREATE_CONTENTFUL_ACTION_FAILED] Create contentful action with identity: \"[New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]\" failed. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[E_PERFORM_EXECUTION_FAILED] Failed to execute DFC operation: Could not check in document 'dfs-2061696922256532526.tmp'. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
[DM_SYSOBJECT_E_LINK_PERMIT2] Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.utils.CmisExceptionFactory.create(CmisExceptionFactory.java:24)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.utils.CmisExceptionBuilder.build(CmisExceptionBuilder.java:31)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.exception.translators.CompoundExceptionTranslator.compoundTranslation(CompoundExceptionTranslator.java:78)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.exception.translators.CompoundExceptionTranslator.translate(CompoundExceptionTranslator.java:28)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.exception.ExceptionTranslator.translate(ExceptionTranslator.java:67)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.action.CreateDocumentAction.execute(CreateDocumentAction.java:66)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.action.CreateDocumentAction.execute(CreateDocumentAction.java:46)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.LinkedActionFilterChain.run(LinkedActionFilterChain.java:23)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.RequestValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestValidationFilter.java:16)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.LinkedActionFilterChain.run(LinkedActionFilterChain.java:21)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.resource.FolderChildrenResource.createDocumentObject(FolderChildrenResource.java:282)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.resource.FolderChildrenResource.createObject(FolderChildrenResource.java:222)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.resource.FolderChildrenResource.moveObject(FolderChildrenResource.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.web.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.CoreServiceException: \"Create\" operation failed for object: [New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.transformation.CoreServiceExceptionContext.execute(CoreServiceExceptionContext.java:31)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.payload.FailOnExceptionPayloadPolicy.execute(FailOnExceptionPayloadPolicy.java:28)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.payload.PayloadPolicy.execute(PayloadPolicy.java:33)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.payload.PayloadPolicy.execute(PayloadPolicy.java:1)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.transformation.DataPackageToDataPackagePayloadAdapter.execute(DataPackageToDataPackagePayloadAdapter.java:27)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.ObjectService.create(ObjectService.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.compat.ClientReflectionServiceInvokerCompat60.invoke(ClientReflectionServiceInvokerCompat60.java:56)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.tx.TxInvocationHandler.invoke(TxInvocationHandler.java:29)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.ReturnedContentTransformationHandler.invoke(ReturnedContentTransformationHandler.java:45)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.OperationOptionsHandler.invoke(OperationOptionsHandler.java:74)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.ServiceContextCleanupHandler.invoke(ServiceContextCleanupHandler.java:31)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.ContextThreadLocalInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextThreadLocalInvocationHandler.java:48)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.ServiceContextInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceContextInvocationHandler.java:30)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.impl.FileRegistryCleanupHandler.invoke(FileRegistryCleanupHandler.java:24)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.action.CreateDocumentAction.execute(CreateDocumentAction.java:59)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.CoreServiceException: Create contentful action with identity: \"[New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]\" failed. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.dfc.CreateAction.createContentfulWithoutSaving(CreateAction.java:192)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.dfc.CreateAction.createObject(CreateAction.java:98)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.dfc.CreateAction.execute(CreateAction.java:81)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.dfc.CreateAction.execute(CreateAction.java:1)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.GraphDataObjectHandler.executeAction(GraphDataObjectHandler.java:45)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.GraphDataObjectHandler.executeAction(GraphDataObjectHandler.java:1)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.graph.GraphProcessor.checkAndProcessNode(GraphProcessor.java:82)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.graph.GraphProcessor.resolveNode(GraphProcessor.java:52)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.graph.GraphProcessor.resolveNode(GraphProcessor.java:57)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.graph.GraphProcessor.processGraph(GraphProcessor.java:22)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.ParentToChildRecursion.execute(ParentToChildRecursion.java:30)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.ParentToChildRecursion.execute(ParentToChildRecursion.java:1)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.transformation.CoreServiceExceptionAdapter.execute(CoreServiceExceptionAdapter.java:32)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.util.SymmetricActionChain.execute(SymmetricActionChain.java:21)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.transformation.CoreServiceExceptionContext.execute(CoreServiceExceptionContext.java:27)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.dfc.DfcOperationException: Create contentful action with identity: \"[New Text Document.txt] [id =null] PROPERTIES [object_name=New Text Document.txt]\" failed. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
    ... 87 more
Caused by: com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.dfc.DfcOperationException: Failed to execute DFC operation: Could not check in document 'dfs-2061696922256532526.tmp'. Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.impl.ActionsFacade.processOperationErrors(ActionsFacade.java:248)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.impl.ActionsFacade.performExecution(ActionsFacade.java:199)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.impl.ActionsFacade.performExecution(ActionsFacade.java:188)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.impl.ActionsFacade.execute(ActionsFacade.java:172)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.execution.proto.dfc.CreateAction.createContentfulWithoutSaving(CreateAction.java:187)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: com.documentum.fc.common.DfException: Linking or unlinking to the folder '/the/folder' failed on sysobject '09003bdd80570f68'. WRITE permit is required on the folder, when using folder security.
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseExceptionMapper.newException(DocbaseExceptionMapper.java:57)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.MessageEntry.getException(MessageEntry.java:39)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseMessageManager.getException(DocbaseMessageManager.java:137)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.checkForMessages(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:310)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.applyForInt(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:581)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection$6.evaluate(DocbaseConnection.java:1331)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.evaluateRpc(DocbaseConnection.java:1129)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.applyForInt(DocbaseConnection.java:1324)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseApi.parameterizedSave(DocbaseApi.java:767)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject$1.evaluate(DfSysObject.java:377)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.util.TransactionalFunctorWithRetry.evaluateUnderTransactionWithDeadlockRetry(TransactionalFunctorWithRetry.java:38)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.util.TransactionalFunctorWithRetry.evaluate(TransactionalFunctorWithRetry.java:25)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.evaluateUnderTransactionWithDeadlockRetry(DfSysObject.java:951)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.doSaveImpl(DfSysObject.java:405)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.doSave(DfSysObject.java:210)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfPersistentObject.saveEx(DfPersistentObject.java:924)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfPersistentObject.save(DfPersistentObject.java:919)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfDocument___PROXY.save(DfDocument___PROXY.java)
    at com.documentum.operations.nodeactions.inbound.DfCheckinObject.checkin(DfCheckinObject.java:235)
    at com.documentum.operations.nodeactions.inbound.DfCheckinObject.execute(DfCheckinObject.java:39)
    at com.documentum.operations.steps.impl.OperationStep.executeStep(OperationStep.java:163)
    at com.documentum.operations.steps.impl.OperationStep.execute(OperationStep.java:41)
    at com.documentum.operations.impl.OperationExecutionEngine.execute(OperationExecutionEngine.java:51)
    at com.documentum.operations.DfOperation.execute(DfOperation.java:401)
    at com.documentum.operations.inbound.impl.InboundOperation.execute(InboundOperation.java:104)
    at com.documentum.operations.inbound.DfImportOperation.execute(DfImportOperation.java:96)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.services.impl.ActionsFacade.performExecution(ActionsFacade.java:197)
    ... 89 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you don't have the permission to create a document in this folder.

Ask your administrator to give you the permission, and the problem will be solved.

The HTTP error status is 500 (Internal Server Error) rather than 403 (Forbidden) which is mandated by the [CMIS specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html), this is a Documentum bug.

Comment: Do you have a KB or issue showing the bug is a known bug?